# Почему не задаются значения по умолчанию

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Пытаюсь сделать значения по умолчанию, а они не ставятся по какой-то причине, можете это заметить на 3 строке, потому что первые 2 сделал в ручном режиме, всё сам прописал, а третья была отправлена через Postman Json-запросом. Значение не ставится как для столбца role, так и для status. Использую postgresql.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему тем, что в Controller прописал сам, что устанавливаю значение "ACTIVE" и всё остальное.

Вот так, например:

```
user.setStatus(Status.ACTIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Галку поставьте Not Null и я думаю, будет счастье..